# Error too many levels of symbolic links con Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Al ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

me sale el siguiente error:

```
ERROR [app 2/5] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wpasupplicant net-tools

 [app 2/5] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wpasupplicant net-tools:

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y wpasupplicant net-tools" did not complete successfully: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/my2mknszq73cbjoxqskad86yf/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
```

En dockerfile tengo esto:

```
FROM python:3.10.12-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wpasupplicant net-tools

COPY ./src/requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./src/ .

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

Pero por lo que vi esta todo correcto

Comment: Puedes indicar el docker-compose.yaml que utilizas? Parece cosa de la sección volumen

Comment: Perdón, he leído mal. Parece un error al hacer el build. Tu docker-compose.yaml utiliza un dockerfile y hay un paso que da error. Puedes poner el dockerfile?